# Does a physical copy of Batman: Arkham City Armored Edition need any extra install size on Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, batman-arkham-city

Does a physical copy of Batman: Arkham City Armored Edition need any extra install size on Wii U, and how much needed space it takes? 
I'm asking because i want to get it but i only have left 3 GB and maybe this game it's heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game has a 1.6 GB mandatory install but will also download files as you are playing and by the end of the game the game data size will be close to **8 GB.**

Comment: So i can't just play and complete the game by just installing 1,6 GB then disconnecting my console from the internet?

Comment: Then you will have a risk. At some point in the story it may request an update from you. At lease this what I encountered on my PS Fallout 3 GOTY

Comment: Thank you, but does happen the same way on Wii U?